# Axes labels with superscript characters and parentheses under library drc

Tags: r, curve-fitting, axes, axis-labels

I'm trying to label a Michaelis-Menten functional response figure.I have tried `bquote` to create accurate axes labels:

Statistics:

```
Michaelis.m1 <- drm(Intake~Clip, Year, data = Michaelis, fct = MM.2())
summary(Michaelis.m1)
```

Plot:

```
plot(Michaelis.m1,log="",xlim=c(0,250), ylim=c(0,60), xlab = expression("Dry Biomass" ~ ("g^{m"^"2})"),
ylab = expression("Intake Rate" ~ (g^{-min}))
```

error message:

```
#plot
> plot(Michaelis.m1,log="",xlim=c(0,250), ylim=c(0,60), xlab = bquote("Dry Biomass (g/m"^"2*")")),
+ ylab = Intake Rate (g/min))
+ )
+ plot(Michaelis.m1,log="",xlim=c(0,250), ylim=c(0,60), xlab = bquote("Dry Biomass ("g/m"^"2*")"),
Error: unexpected string constant in:
")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't want "min" in the exponent, but you want "-1" in the exponent (grams per minute).

```
par(ps=10, mgp=c(2.5,0.75,0))
plot(1:10, ylab=bquote(g~min^-1))
```

It was a bit hard to understand what you question was, but I think the above code produces the desired effect. The call to `par()` was just to clean up the graph a bit, because the exponent got cut off otherwise.